# Battery Pack for Metz 64

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, off-camera-flash, battery

Are there any recommended battery packs for the Metz 64? I've seen many for the Metz 58 and I presume they use the same connector?

From these Amazon links [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D06LUAA), [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N5FC4ZG) and [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FB6JK4U), it seems that all of them have mixed review and some suggest that the pack mainly works for Canikon variants and not Metz or have no comments on what flash they use.

Does anyone have any experience in using any of the battery packs with Metz flashes or alternatively does anyone have any recommendations for good, working, reliable battery packs for Metz systems? I've seen the native one for ~$400-500 but I'm looking for an alternative solution that's cheaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metz 64 is using the same V58-50 cable as 58 AF-2 and AF-1. You can use Quantum MKZ3, and something like their Battery 1.